# django 1.3: values and annotate with foreign keys and many to many relationships

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I got these models:

```
from django.db import models

class Feed(models.Model):
    readers = models.ManyToManyField('auth.user')
    # other fields

class Entry(models.Model):
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed)
    read_by = models.ManyToManyField('auth.user')
    # other fields
```

A `Feed` instance has all of it's readers in the `readers` set. If an `User` reads an `Entry`, the `User` is added to the `read_by` set.

Now I'm stuck with the following problem: How can I get for one `User` the count of unread `Entries` for every `Feed` the `User` reads?

Coming from the `Feed` side, the following statement excluded me all `Feeds` with read `Entries` for the given `User`:

```
Feed.objects.filter(readers=user).values('public_id').annotate(models.Count('entry')).exclude(entry__read_by=user)
```

Coming from the other `Entry` side, the following statement does not group the `Feeds` and the counts together:

```
 Entry.objects.exclude(read_by=user).filter(feed__readers=user).values('feed').annotate(models.Count('id'))
```

**Edit:**

I was asked to provide example data. So think of the following setup:

`User` U reads three `Feeds`: FeedOne, FeedTwo, FeedThree.

For every `Feed` there are currently five `Entries` in database. Two `Entries` of FeedOne are already read by `User` U.

Summary:

```
FeedOne
    EntryA (read by U)
    EntryB (read by U)
    EntryC
    EntryD
    EntryE
FeedTwo
    EntryF
    EntryG
    EntryH
    EntryI
    EntryJ
FeedThree
    EntryK
    EntryL
    EntryM
    EntryN
    EntryO
```

What I need is the count of the unread `Entries` for each `Feed` of this `User`:

```
FeedOne: 3
FeedTwo: 5
FeedThree: 5
```

Comment: Can you post example data and expected query result ? I think this would make your question much easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
feed_qs = user.feed_set.exclude(entry__read_by=user).annotate(unread_count=Count('entry'))
for feed if feed_qs:
    print feed, feed.unread_count
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses

Comment: I have a test db with 5 Feeds. One user is reader for all feeds, but has only read entries from 1 of those feeds. With your query, I only get the counts for the 4 other feeds, but not for that with the already read entries.